# Laravel Jetstream problem with Bazar vendor package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream, laravel-breeze

i am using Laravel 8.3, and i already have installed Jetstream with Fortify package for login on frontend, it's work i can login, but i needit to install package Bazar: https://github.com/conedevelopment/bazar
In that docs of bazar, it's say to install breeze, i want to stay on jetstream to don't make code to big.
When i am logged in, in try to access url with /bazar, but say `403 This action is unauthorized.`
I tried to install clean bazar, and work with breeze, what i am doing wrong ?

This is composer.json:

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "conedevelopment/bazar": "^0.9.1",
    "donatello-za/rake-php-plus": "^1.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "intervention/image": "^2.6",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
    "laravel/jetstream": "^2.3",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
    "laravel/socialite": "^5.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.3",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
    "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",
    "yoeunes/toastr": "^1.2"
},
```

Doc image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the login method Breeze or Jetstream, both use laravel auth, problem was Bazar, in config/bazar.php, you have a key

```
'admins' => [
        'xx@m.com',
    ],
```

There you need to add email to have permision to view the backend of Bazar